# Make button has same size as inputs

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, input

I have form with inputs/selects and one button.

If Button is `<button/>` then I have problems with it size in FF browser (it's bigger than inputs).

If Button is `<input/>` then I have problems with button text (I can't set it to be in the middle of button for all browsers).

Here is example (with `<button>` and with `<input>`)

**[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm00ue9h/1/)**

Comment: Please don't use inline CSS. Mixing external CSS and inline CSS is even worse. It's not readable and is hard to get an idea about what's going on with your styling.

Comment: @TJ, sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

Hi use padding instead of height for the buttons:

```
.form-search input.search-input, .form-search select.search-input, form input.search-input, form select.search-input {
    padding:  0 20px 0 20px;
    margin: 3px 0;
}
```

Comment: your using default inputs with no styles so they will look different in different browser no matter what, the above snippet of code i gave you fix's the size* problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem which I had with different browsers. You can use `jQuery` to find out if the browser is FireFox, use the referring  `css`, and if the browser is Chrome or Safari, use another `css`, to gain your requirements.